# Passing initializer as argument

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer

Does initializer have a type? if so, what's? in this case, how could I make the following code work?

```
template <typename T>
int f(T a)
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    f({1,2});
}
```

It give following error:

> c.cpp:32:2: error: no matching function for call to 'f'
>           f({1,2});
>           ^ c.cpp:18:5: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T' int f(T a)
>       ^ 1 error generated.

Comment: `{1,2}` is not even an expression. And it cannot be deduced other than for an parameter pattern of the form `std::initializer_list<pattern>` (where `pattern` is something like `T const&`).

Comment: [temp.deduct.call]/1 " If removing references
and cv-qualifiers from `P` gives `std::initializer_list<P'>` for some `P'` and the argument is an initializer
list, then deduction is performed instead for each element of the initializer list, taking `P'` as a function
template parameter type and the initializer element as its argument. Otherwise, an initializer list argument
causes the parameter to be considered a non-deduced context."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When writing `f({1,2})` you are using [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

If you want to pass the [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) `{1,2}` to a function as is you can do it like this:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
int f(std::initializer_list<T> a) {
    for(const T& x : a) {
        std::cout << x << ", " << std::endl; // do something with the element
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    f({1,2});
}
```

Comment: You probably meant the statement inside the loop to use `x`, not `a`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to execute your function for each value in the list, you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
int f(T a)
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    for (int a : {1,2})
        std::cout << f(a) << std::endl;
}
```

Note this requires c++11 compatible compiler

If you want to pass the list to your function, then something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename T>
int f(T a)
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << f(std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2}) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You can also exploit the <strike>misdesign</strike> feature of auto+uniform init: `auto il{1,2}; f(il);`